# Memory Problems with ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

I am having trouble with memory allocation during a stress/performance testing of a program. In the test, I tried to do loading/unloading same set of resources again and again. The error I got was "Error, #1000, out of memory". The stack trace was about `URLLoader/onComplete` and `URLStream/readBytes`. I checked the memory being used at the time of failure, it was less than the maximum amount that the program has used before. I don't think it's caused by memory leak because the memory used through time is pretty consistent (allocate when loading resources, deallocate, allocate, ...) Also, this problem happens kinda randomly. I am kind of stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Flex Builder, use the flex profiler to get a better idea of memory being used by various objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can also monitor memory consumption with something as simple as ProcessExplore for Windows or Activity Monitor for Mac. If all you're doing is loading/unloading resources, and you are managing the life of these resources correctly (i.e. removing listeners, making available for garbage collection, etc), then you should see a very consistent peak/valley memory graph. If the memory continues to rise, you've got a leak. Be especially careful if the resources you are loading/unloading are bitmaps as bitmapdata tends to be a prime culprit in flash memory leaks. Good luck!

Comment: it's way better to use flash' internal reporting, there's no guarantee flash will return the memory to the os once it's done with it.

Comment: Perhaps... but using an OS memory profiler will uncover blatant memory leaks and can be a good place to start. I do agree with Amarghosh though that using the Flex Profiler is your best bet for uncovering the problem.